# Gradient Clipping - Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent, object-detection-api

I am struggling with consistently getting the following errors when trying to train my dataset:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): LossTensor is inf or nan. : Tensor had NaN values
```

or

```
NanLossDuringTrainingError
```

I feel like the only workaround at this point is using gradient clipping, but I'm unsure of how to integrate that into the pipeline.config file or into the optimizerbuilder.py file. I've tried reorganizing my directories, double checking the coordinates of my bounding boxes, resizing my images, using both the FaceSSD model and the Faster RCNN Inception V2 Coco model, changing from RMS prop optimizer to Adam optimizer, decreasing my learning rate, and using legacy/train.py instead of model_main.py. Does anyone have advice?

Comment: Usually that means that your learning rate is way too high

Comment: You can define `gradient_clipping_by_norm` in the train part of your config file. But  I am not sure if this solves your problem, I would also suggest that either your batch size is too small or learning rate is too high.